# Considerar a vigência final até o dia seguinte as 03 horas da manhã utilizando PLSQL

Tags: pl-sql, oracle11c

**Pessoal, preciso fazer a seguinte validação:**
Quando um registro entrar na minha base de dados, preciso validar qual a data de vigência deste registro.
Se a vigência estiver entre a data atual então o registro é válido.
**Ex:**
Vigência de 12/03/2015 a 13/03/2015, a vigência termina em 13/03/2015 correto?
Mas preciso considerar a data final até o dia 14/03/2015 as 03:00 da manhã, depois deste horário a data final não será mais válida.
Alguém tem alguma idéia de como posso criar esta regra?

Comment: Faltam detalhes do tipo , qual estrutura das tabelas envolvidas ? Que TYPES ? Que campo é validado contra o que ? Em tese uma CHECK CONSTRAINT ou uma TRIGGER podem resolver o problema, mas faltam detalhes para uma resposta.

Comment: Pq precisaria da estrutura? É apenas uma regra. Os types são datas. No caso a base é a data de vigência final, preciso que ela seja considerada como verdadeira até as 03:00 da manhã do dia seguinte!

Comment: O valor que vai entrar deve estar entre a data correte e a próxima data (com as 3h) certo ? Hoje seria 13/03/2015 03:01 e 14/03/2015 03:00 , sefor , tente uma trigger de validação que faça esta regra.

Comment: Sim, é que no caso minha dúvida não é o qual objeto eu usuária para fazer, no meu caso é como eu faria mesmo para considerar isto. Editei a descrição do problema, acho que ficou melhor agora!

Answer (score 1):

Algo assim

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TABELA
  BEFORE
    INSERT OR
    UPDATE 
  ON TABELA
BEGIN
  /*3 horas de "hoje" até 3 horas de "amanhã"*/
  IF NOT (DATA BETWEEN (TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 3/24) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) + 3/24)) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'DATA INVÁLIDA PARA PERÍODO');
  END IF;
END;
/
```